# Jquery can't add class to dynamicly added nav-link

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, bootstrap-4

I have a JQuery code that adds a nav-link dynamicly to a nav-item. The problem is this nav-link doesn't change to active when clicked. I tried to dynamicly give it the active class but it doesn't take it. it seems after the page reloads everything is rest and it's always the first nav-link that takes the active class.

[image]

It's of course wrapped inside `$(document).read()`. I also tried to wrap it inside  `$(window).load()` but same problem.

```js
$('#A').append('<li class="nav-item">' + '<a class="nav-link" href="{{dynamic_link}}?id=1" >Dynamicly Added</a>' + '</li>');


$(document).on('click', '.collapse li', function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse mt-5 h-100  justify-content-between" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
  <ul class="navbar-nav accordion" id="SideBar">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{{index}}">home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{{list}}">list</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#A" aria-controls="collapseOne"> A </a>
    </li>

    <ul class="collapse" id="A" data-parent="#SideBar">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{B}}">B</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{C}}">C</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you can spot the problem I'd appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Could not reproduce the issue, better if you create an executable code snippet of the issue.

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to create the snippet cause i'm working with DTL too.

Answer (score 0):

Because elements that you are appending not exist when you define the the click handler better to use the delegate() method from jQuery.

```js
 $('#A').append(
                '<li class="nav-item">'
                +'<a class="nav-link" href="{{dynamic_link}}?id=1" >Dynamicly Added</a>'
                +'</li>') ; 
         
$('.collapse ').delegate('li','click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
   $( this ).addClass( 'active' ).siblings().removeClass( 'active' );
});
```

```css
.collapse li.active a{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse mt-5 h-100  justify-content-between" id="navbarsExampleDefault" >
    <ul class="navbar-nav accordion" id="SideBar">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{index}}">home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{list}}" >list</a>
        </li>

         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#A"  aria-controls="collapseOne" > A </a>
        </li>
       

         <ul class="collapse"  id="A" data-parent="#SideBar" >
            
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{B}}" >B</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{C}}" >C</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
```

Comment: I appreciate your reproduction, the problem is I shouldn't preventdefault otherwise it won't send to the link. I tried it witothout preventdefault but it's the same problem as when it loads the new page the code won't be applied.

Comment: i'm not sure that i completely understand what benefits are you trying to reach. What for are you trying to add some actions or classes if page will be refreshed by href links? Could you clarify a bit your task? step by step

Comment: when you click the nav-link it sends you to another page where you want that nav-link to be active.

Comment: so there is nothing to do with click events. NoT Logic! just during page generation it is needed to check if href attribute equal to current page

Comment: as I said it didn't work. I even used $(window).on('load',

Comment: @nassim i dont understand what for you need "active" class on li element to be setted up by script if after navigation to another URL it will dissapear.  If you need to show current page in menu as active after refres with some css rules then it needed to get current url  var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only (/path/example.html)
var url      = window.location.href;     // Returns full URL(https://example.com/path/example.html)
var origin   = window.location.origin;   // Returns base URL (https://example.com)
and compare it with href in your links

Comment: I checked the current path and compared it to the hrefs but still nothing. Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231850/discussion-between-asturion-and-nassim).